# What would be a poetic word for a place or vessel where elements interact and create something new and beautiful?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word that represents a place or a vessel where things interact to create something new and beautiful.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example of such an interaction.

Comment: If you search here for synergy, synchronicity, and serendipity you'll find a lot of similar questions with a lot of terms.

Answer (score 4):

Try **crucible**

> (*literal meaning*) a vessel of a very refractory material (such as porcelain) used for melting and calcining a substance that requires a high degree of heat

> (*figurative meaning*) a place or situation in which concentrated forces interact to cause or influence change or development

*His character was formed in the crucible of war.*

[*Merriam-Webster*]

**The Crucible Of Life**

*Into the crucible, stirred by the years*,

*Go all our hopes and misgivings and fears*;

*Glad days and sad days, our pleasures and pains*,

*Worries and comforts, our losses and gains*.

*Out of the crucible shall there not come*

*Joy undefiled when we pour off the scum*?

Edgar A. Guest

Comment: The [Crucible Theatre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucible_Theatre) in Sheffield, UK is aptly named, also because of Sheffield's historic production of steel.